# React clearInterval doesn't stop when using another state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-statements, setinterval

I have a small app that is playing some audios when I press play and stops when I press the button again using isPlaying state. The functionality of play/stop works good, but I want to add a progress bar to show the song's progress. I used useEffect and a "completed" state
so that the progress bar will show the progress with css styling. everything works, except that I can't clear the interval. When I press stop, the song stops, but the progress bar continues, after checking I figured that clearInterval doesn't work. This is my useEffect function:

```
  const ProgressBar = ({isPlaying}) => {
        const [completed, setCompleted] = useState({
            count: 0
        });
        
         useEffect(() => {
        if (isPlaying){
             setInterval(() => {
                setCompleted(completed.count+=5.8)
                if(completed.count > 99) {
                    setCompleted(completed.count=0);
                } 
            }, 1000);
        }
        else {
            clearInterval()
            
        }
    }, [isPlaying]);
```

I tried to add:

```
const intervalId = setInterval(() => { ...
```

and then pass the intervalId to clear(intervalId)
but then I need to add condition of - if (isPlaying) before that.
and when I do so, I can't use `"else { clearInterval(intervalId)}`
Because IntervalId is undefined under the else scope.
How can I pass that and clear the interval?
I tried multiple ways which didn't work for some reason. Any help would be appreciated!

Edited:

I tried to console log just to make sure the playing state get the change from the play/stop toggle, and it works ok:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    if (isPlaying) {
        console.log("playing")
    }
    else {
        console.log("not playing")
    }
```

I have "ControlPanel" component, so I can't configure the ProgressBar component functionality with the buttons functionality:

```
        const ControlPanel = ({
setIsLooping, isLooping, isPlaying, setIsPlaying}) => {
      return ( 
        <div> 
        <PlayButton>
            {!isPlaying ? (
            <button type="button" 
            className="play" 
            onClick={() => setIsPlaying(true)}> 
            <ImPlay2></ImPlay2> Play 
            </button>
            ) : (
            <button type="button"
            className="pause"
            onClick={() => setIsPlaying(false)}> 
            <ImStop></ImStop> Stop 
            </button> 
            )}
        </PlayButton>
            <Flex> .....
```

Comment: could you share your repo link or StackBlitz?

Comment: What is setCompleted and completed?  useState?  Is completed.count defined?

Comment: Yes, thanks:   https://github.com/shiranox/audio-player

Comment: I edited my question with completed state

Answer (score 0):

use can store `setInterval` id in ref

```
const intervalId = useRef(null)

useEffect(() => {
    if (isPlaying){
        intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
            setCompleted(completed.count+=5.8)
            if(completed.count > 99) {
                setCompleted(completed.count=0);
            } 
        }, 1000);
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(intervalId.current)
    }

    // it's better to clean up your component
    return () => {
       clearInterval(intervalId.current)
    }

}, [isPlaying]);
```

Comment: This works, but one time only. when I press play again, the progress bar stays in the last state, and doesn't progress. I also get an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'count' on number '11.6' (meaning that the state doesn't resets to 0. I tried to add   setCompleted(completed.count=0);  but then the progress bar doesn't work at all.

Comment: can you try to store your  `setInterval` id in the `state`?

Comment: Yes, I tried:     const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState (useRef(null))   //////

then : useEffect(() => {
        if (isPlaying){
            setIntervalId(setInterval(() => { ...